# spring 3 + hibernate 4 + user authentication and authorization privileges

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

**`Status:`** Waiting for comprehensive answers with code examples concerning dao, service, controller, view.

With spring 3 + hibernate 4, in a service, dao, controller, view (mvc scenario), like http://www.cavalr.com/blog/Spring_3_and_Annotation_Based_Hibernate_4_Example , 
where is the good place to have authentications before doing something. e.g

**Occasions:**

1. Is user logged in? (first check by session , then by data base username password match)

session made? getting previous session on every transaction and authenticating if no session has made.

2. More authentications for every transaction e.g:
   get some value or boolean from database, check if its true (e.g can this user add more users), then proceed.
3. Does user have permissions?  and if authentication fails, how to respond to user?

**Ways to respond:**

a. Redirect to error page (dont like that though)

b. redirect to the same page with an error message (ok)

c. Do all with ajax, (most preferred) dont reload or redirect page, just authentication by

1. session and or
2. database
3. send error message on the same page by ajax.
4. proceed if authentication succeeds.

**Where to put the logic? in dao, service, controller?**
What options do I have?

Can some one give a **sample code?** I have googled but found irrelevent examples.
I know one solution is spring security, but what do you think? and is there a sample code for it that covers all my questions?

Example scenario:

[image]

my scenarios is like this. a user comes and a db query tels/lists the borads he has access to. when he enters a board. the boxes privileges are lists and only readable boxes are shown to him.  then same with tasks.     each of them has  create/read/update/delete permision   and that is known/fetched at the time when the user acts for one. e.g tries to create/read/update/delete a   board/box/task.

now there are millions of boxes / tasks.       loading permissions for each might be insane?

I do not understand how to and where to do the authentication and authorization. daos, services,controllers, and then sending the problems to views as error messages. One dao may call another, one service may call another dao(s) and / or service. all or most may give authorization failures. how to pass the failure strings to view placing them accordingly?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too wide. You ask about implementation of everything. There are too many ways to implement it and should be discussed a lot. You can use ajax for it or do not use it, it's up to you and your requirements.

Comment: Please split your question into multiple questions. It will be much easier to help you.